# cash note looking for small change of coin equally

Tags: python

Problem: i have cash in my hand, with this programming, i would get small changes of coin equally,
e.g. coin = [0.5, 0.2, 0.1]
if i have $2, system would return to me $0.5: 1unit, $0.2: 3 unit, $0.1: 4 unit

## system wont goes all to $0.5, but will allocate to different face value of coin

code didnt functioning, no looping and end.

```
amount = int(input("enter money: "))

global ncoin
global coin

def payCash(amount):

  coin = [5, 2, 1]
  ncoin = [0, 0, 0]
  while amount > 0:
     for cash in (coin):
        if amount - int(cash) > 0:
             amount = amount - cash
            if cash == 5:
                ncoin[0] += 1
            elif cash == 2:
                ncoin[1] += 1
            else:
                ncoin[2] += 1

  print("$5:" , ncoin[0] , " $2:" , ncoin[1] , " 1:" , ncoin[2])

print("money")
```

error:

```
enter money: 20
money

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: you are not actually calling the function... add `payCash(amount)` before the last print

Comment: i tried, but it turns up, loading never came with result, even print("money") also not showing

Comment: You'll have an endless loop since your if statement stops the amount from ever reaching below 0 because it never deducts to an amount below 0

Comment: so any suggestion of coding?

Comment: i'm thinking, it can stop when comes to 0

Comment: `if amount - int(cash) >= 0:`. Also your indentations are a little off... try to fix them so it is easier to help you

Comment: Little difficult to suggest from mobile potentially the if statement should be .`>=` but I'm  not able to test. Was just pointing out the error to help other answerers or yourself to pinpoint the issue

Comment: You're very welcome

Comment: In order to get 4 coins of 5 for an input of 20, I would also recommend adding a `break` after the last `else`

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
if amount - int(cash) >= 0:
```